# MCU Input ESD Protection + debounce

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, esd, surge-protection

I'm working on a device which requires reading from a reed switch (slow, water meter) which should work in a bit noisy environment (a few relays switching back/forth on the same board, triacs and contactors for 3-phase motors distanced however electrically connected to the same STM32).
I would like to get rid of ringing/induced voltage spikes/ESDs. IN1 is connected to the reed switch, other terminal goes to a GND.

[image: STM32 input protection]

STM32 is powered from a 3V3 rail, which is formed from a 12V rail by a DC-DC.
I've used optocoupler to avoid possible ESD voltage inducing directly to the STM32 pin, since IN1 ( +GND) terminals are supposed to be wired with a realtively long wires to a reed device.
D11 is for protecting optocoupler's diode from reverse voltage (6V max), and also there is a TVS (24Vbr rated, just because i have the one already in the scheme can be replaced with a more appropriate one).

Reed switch will be located near a 3-phase AC motor (>= 15kW, up to 55kW, just nearby, no connections).

1. Does the circuit make any sense (in terms of ESD protection)?

> have doubts since MCU still shares the same GND with a reed switch and
> connected indirectly with a 12V via DC-DC

2. Can the optocoupler be safely replaced with a transistor?

**P.S.** buck converter is additionaly filtered with a 1.6 kHz RC net (R16-C7) to avoid spikes propagation from a 12V rail (relay coils are 12V-controllable, at least 4 relays can be switched at once).

[image: buck regulator input]

Comment: You can likely remove all of this and replace it with a N channel MOSFET, a series resistor to the MCU, a TVS and maybe some protection diodes against wrong voltage levels. The buck coverter sounds like a separate question.

Comment: thanks for a suggestion. buck converter info is just to show a connection between 12v and 3v rails

Comment: but isn't fet's gate sensible to the ESDs?

Comment: Yeah hence the TVS but I think I misunderstood what you are doing, you aren't actually supplying the switch this way, just reading it. So there's no need for a MOSFET either.

Comment: If you're keeping the opto, for ESD, you may as well put the 3k3 resistor on pin 2 of the opto, i.e. going to your switch. That'll limit max current into the diode while the TVS is clamping, or while it's in the process of turning on. The way the ground is connected in layout might potentially defeat some of the benefit of the optoisolation, too. The photodiode side of the opto circuit should return to the 12V circuit, in terms of layout, even if they're "the same ground".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general-purpose input circuit for industrial applications might look along the lines of this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZANHX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- TVS rated according to what you expect, typically 24V nominal and if so maybe 36Vbr TVS. Or maybe 18Vbr for 12V nominal. Exact values are not critical, pick some standard one that's highly available. If rated at some 1500W "peak pulse", then that's good enough to handle most industry EMC requirements.
- R2 is optional as a voltage divider together with R1 to take it down to MCU levels. If you don't need a voltage divider then remove R2 and put 10k or so at R1.
- D1/D2 are plain old signal diodes to keep the voltage levels within limits. Assuming roughly 0.7Vfwd in D1, then a zener D3 of 0.7 + 2.6V will cap voltages at 3.3V, for a 3.3V MCU.
- C1 is optional to filter misc radiated high frequency RF signals.
- On top of it, the MCU is not older than 25 years back or so and therefore got half-decent protection diodes built-in.

There's some sort of inflation of optocouplers on this site. When designing for tough environments, that should be far from the first tool you reach for.

That tool should rather be the *awesome* component known as a series resistor: they get rid of all manner of problems including ESD, accidental shorts, overcurrents, stray currents, circuit faults etc etc. Even EMI at some extent.

Optocouplers are generally to be avoided unless you are doing something specialized, like designing isolated power electronics or dealing with really bad grounds like in maritime applications, or perhaps when facing extreme EMI requirements (aerospace/military) that rule out inductance-based isolation.

Comment: Agree to most things, but instead of D1 D2, what I do, is to add a pair of Schottkies directly to the supplies of the receiving IC. This will limit the pin voltage to ~0.3 V beyond the supplies which will be still completely fine and not activate any internal steering or parasitic diodes that might cause latch-up.

Comment: @tobalt That sounds like a nice trick to lower the BoM a bit indeed, never thought of that :) Although some special parts like the ADC inside some MCUs may go latch up if you stray just a few hundred mV beyond Vref.

Comment: Good circuit, though I respectfully differ regarding optocouplers in industrial. Those systems are often low production volume, high cost of downtime. Low volume means never get opportunity to shake out all bugs thru the kind of exhaustive FMEA you might see in smth like automotive, and high downtime cost justifies the "belt and suspenders" approach. Also opto totally bypasses questions of different power zones with different grounds

Comment: @PeteW Except optocouplers are IMO not "belt and suspenders" but rather an additional source of problems. As for volumes, it depends on what you mean with "industrial". Typical automation factory lines are low volume indeed, but generic control systems are not. The kind of products I'm used at roll out a couple of thousand units per year at least. Not nearly as cost-sensitive as consumer electronics, but why paid extra for some "silicon dummy" part that just sits on the BoM and does me no good.

Comment: @Lundin - I'm looking at specialty modules in the hundreds/y, but personal experience is, there's quite a bit of variation in how integrators put together their systems. Some dutifully run a return line for each signal, others minimize their own wiring and ground the sensor or switch to the nearest available place, which they treat as magically common. Then when "it doesn't work", which might or might not be because of this, all signaling is in doubt. And they rack up dozens of person-hours per incident before it even escalates to someone who understands it. Hence the paranoid attitude :-P

Comment: @PeteW Oh yeah I totally recognize this "ground it wherever you like" practice, particularly so in vehicle electronics where everything is always grounded to chassis. But you can use other forms of isolators than optocoupler, namely the inductance-based "digital isolators" nowadays available from lots of different vendors. These are more reliable in my experience, particularly if your products have a long life in the field.

Comment: I worked a lot with electronics on excavators and heavy machinery where they would first merrily ignore the signal ground you provided, then attach the supply ground - which now becomes the signal reference - of your device to some godawful "star ground" where all massive surges from the whole machine live. Then they run starter motors or big time hydraulic vales and wonder why there are problems... "we used a star ground, it solves everything!" Err, that is indeed good practice but please don't use that as signal reference for my CAN bus, please! :)

Comment: @Lundin sorry, forgot to mention the circuit is battery-powered, so i'm wondering how much will D3+R3 draw? or zenner should activate only on overvoltages and normally does not?

Comment: also regarding '_Optocouplers are generally to be avoided_' - i have them to drive relay-enable switch. If all of those (relay+MCU) sitting on the same ground (within the same PCB) - should i get rid of opto and just leave a transistor? (relay coils are paralleled with a diodes)

Comment: @TarasShcherban You can take R3 fairly high to cap the current draw. With 0.7V across and some 47k, 100k or whatever, we're down to a few microampere. And that current only passes when there is no input voltage present. Though tobalt's idea above of using two schottky instead might be worth investigating too.

Comment: @TarasShcherban Regarding relays then yeah it is sufficient to just have a transistor, as long as you provide a freewheel diode across the relay coil, which is important & mandatory. ULN Darlington arrays are common for relay driving since they come with the diodes built-in.